# Django / Python, using variablized object names

Tags: python, django, object, import

I'm confused on how to do this, I'm passing in a dictionary with different values, such as "app" which is the name of the app (so that I can better decouple code for easier modularization).. so this is just a simplified example and its not working so I'm wondering how to use the variable "app" within the string that is calling the models import.. thanks for any advice

```
infodict={'app':'myappname'}
app = infodict['app']
from web1.app.models import modelname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like [importlib](http://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html) (Python 2.7). If you version of Python doesn't have `importlib` then you can use plain old [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

For example:

```
import sys
module_name = "web1.%s.models" % app
__import__(module_name)
models = sys.modules[module_name]
models.modelname
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use [contenttypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)